# Clarifying how Lambda expression works in the official Java tutorial

Tags: java

I've read the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) over and over again and I just don't understand the last part of approach 6.

Spcifically this part:

```
public static void printPersonsWithPredicate(
    List<Person> roster, Predicate<Person> tester) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (tester.test(p)) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, the following method invocation is the same as when you invoked printPersons in Approach 3: Specify Search Criteria Code in a Local Class to obtain members who are eligible for Selective Service:

```
printPersonsWithPredicate(
    roster,
    p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
        && p.getAge() >= 18
        && p.getAge() <= 25
);
```

So if **p** is a generic type how does it know it is a Person? I just don't get how it can distinguish itself as a person and later invoke the Person methods - getGender() and getAge(). Does p in this case refer to the class object of the surrounding class?

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on the provided answers, is this correct?

***The following code:***

```
interface CheckPerson {
    boolean test(Person p);
}

class CheckPersonEligibleForSelectiveService implements CheckPerson {
    public boolean test(Person p) {
        return p.gender == Person.Sex.MALE &&
            p.getAge() >= 18 &&
            p.getAge() <= 25;
    }
}

public static void printPersons(
    List<Person> roster, CheckPerson tester) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (tester.test(p)) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}

printPersons(roster, new CheckPersonEligibleForSelectiveService());
```

***Is the same as:***

```
import java.util.function // import the Predicate<T> interface

public static void printPersonsWithPredicate(
    List<Person> roster, Predicate<Person> tester) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (tester.test(p)) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}

printPersonsWithPredicate(
    roster,
    p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
        && p.getAge() >= 18
        && p.getAge() <= 25
);
```

***Because:***

1. Predicate interface is already defined in java.util.function
2. By declaring Predicate as Person in the method argument:

   1. we are implicitly implementing Predicate with a type of Person, and
   2. when invoking the method with a generic type T (or lack thereof), the type is implicitly inferred by the method as Person

If I am wrong, please let me know, so that I can update my understanding. I really want to get this right.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzO5GSujdqI - I found this video which has a very good explanation around "type inference" at 30 minutes as eluded by one of the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: the parameter is simply **inferred from the type signature of the relevant functional interface, including any additional limitations to the generic parameter**.

In this case, we know that the second argument is a `Predicate<T>`. Since `Predicate<T>` is a functional interface with the method [`test(T t)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test-T-), we know that the type of `p` is `T` (and **not `Predicate<T>`**).

And since **`T` is limited to `Person` by the signature of `printPersonsWithPredicate(List<Person> roster, Predicate<Person> tester)`**, the actual type of `p` is `Person`.

---

**RE: UPDATE** - the answer is both "yes" and "no" :).

"Yes", in general the sequence of type inference could be described this way.

"No", for the following reasons:

- in 2.2, I'd say it is better to state that **the method *limits* the type of `T` to `Person`**. The type person is simply the "common denominator" of what is allowed. For example: if the signature of the method would would contain:

  - `Predicate<? extends JLabel>` - then the argument type would effectively be `JLabel`.
  - `Predicate<?>` - then the argument type would effectively be `Object`.
- it is better to state the the **compiler infers** something about types, rather than something is "implicitly defined" by something else than the compiler. You may regard it as a nitpick, but this switch has two important consequences:

  - it can save you **from reasoning pitfalls** of the form "it's not X that does N, it's Y".
  - very specifically, since the compiler is able to infer that a type of the `Predicate<Person>` is legal, there is **no need to actually *create* a new anonymous class** that implements a functional interface. Indeed, in Java 8's current JDK, **that's what happens**. [Here's an article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood) explaining the details.

Comment: Thank you, this kinda make sense to me. However, I'm still a little bit confused. I've updated my question to clarify my understanding based on your answer. Please let me know if I have it right.

Comment: @user3804927 : I see someone already has added an answer regarding the update, but just in case, I've edited in a "clean room" response.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda expression is a definition for the body of [`Predicate<Person>#test`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test-T-), which will take a `Person` as a parameter. We know this because `printPersonsWithPredicate` is declared to take a `Predicate<Person>`, which the lambda is being passed as an argument for.

The syntax of a lambda is that the left hand side of the `->` is the parameter list for the method that is being defined:

```
(Person p) -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
    && p.getAge() >= 18
    && p.getAge() <= 25
```

However, the compiler is able to determine that the singular parameter `p` of the lambda must be a Person so it can be omitted. Hence the shortened form `p -> ...`.

An anonymous class near-equivalent to the lambda is shown in [Approach #4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach4).

Comment: Thank you, this kinda make sense to me. However, I'm still a little bit confused. I've updated my question to clarify my understanding based on your answer. Please let me know if I have it right.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the **UPDATE** questions only ...

> 1) Predicate interface is already defined in java.util.function

Correct

> 2) By declaring Predicate as Person in the method argument:

Incorrect.

You are actually declaring `tester` as `Predicate<Person>`.  You are not declaring `Predicate` at all here.  `Predicate` is a standard interface that it declared by the standard libraries.

> 2a) we are implicitly implementing Predicate with a type of Person

Correct ... sort of.  You are *explicitly* implementing it.  And the type of the lambda that is required here is explicitly *specified* ... by the method signature of `printPersonsWithPredicate`.  Specifically, because you declared the formal parameter `tester` to have type `Predicate<Person>`.

> 2b) when invoking the method with a generic type T (or lack thereof), the type is implicitly inferred by the method as Person

Not in this case.

Comment: Thank you, the part I was really confused about was with the Type inference, which has been explained in the previous post, and further clarified in a YouTube video. When working with boolean, JDK 8 introduced the concept of Predicate, and through Type Inference (again a new concept in Java), the compiler is able to determine the type of p.